# Python rest_framework como mudar URL?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Alguém como posso mudar os urls no rest_framework no django?

O router define como padrão o uso do ID da criatura nos URL
ex. /api/creatures/1/

Eu quero que ao invés de aparecer o ID, apareça o nome da criatura.

ex. /api/creature/dragon/

## serializer.py

```
class CreatureSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Creature
        fields = ['url', 'name', 'experience', 'level', 'description', 'resistance', 'drop', 'rare_drop']
```

## router.py

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'creatures', CreatureViewSet, basename='creature')

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em "views.py" na definição da classe que deve ser algo como `CreatureViewSet()` você deve colocar o atributo `lookup_field` com o valor do campo que você deseja usar:

```py
class CreatureViewSet(...):
    ...
    lookup_field = "name"
    ...
```

Daí você conseguirá o acesso a partir do nome, ou seja, ao invés de "/api/pizza/3" você usará "/api/pizza/calabresa".

Dica: crie um campo de *slug* para guardar o nome ao invés de usar o nome como referência já que "Calabresa" e "calabresa" não serão a mesma coisa.

Comment: Esse campo slug eu coloco onde? No proprio ViewSet?

Comment: Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "creature-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field. to com esse problema agora